# Extracting specific data from a table using Scala?

Tags: scala, dataframe

Heres a sample DF:

```
Date            Party name                  Symbol  Buy/Sell indicator   # of shares   trade price
2011-01-03      American Funds EuPc;A       AAPL    BUY                     2400          332.87
2011-02-14      American Funds CWGI;A       SLB     BUY                     6700          94.08
2011-01-06      Tudor Investment Corp       ALL     BUY                     11800         31.92
2011-01-20      American Funds Inc;A        AMZN    SELL                    3600          180.14
```

And here is what I wish to achieve:

```
Date            Party name                 Symbol  Buy/Sell     # of shares   trade price  trading volume 

2011-04-21      Federated Prime Obl;Inst    MMM     BUY          2600         96.17        250042
2011-01-05      Fortress Investment Group   CMCSA   SELL         29700        21.96        644193
2011-02-28      Dodge & Cox Intl Stock      DELL    SELL         57400        15.67        899458
2011-05-02      American Funds Inc;A        S       BUY          137300       5.19         712587
```

The new trading volume column is the `# of shares` column * `trade price` column. Anyone know how to achieve this automatically since there are a lot more lines? What I would like to do after is take the trading volume values and show them as an output in descending order. The exact instruction is

> The biggest dollar trading volume counter parties, top twenty list.

I have this so far:

```
val dataframe = spark.read.cvs("c:\data")

val newdf = dataframe.select("# of shares","trade price")
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val newdf = dataframe.withColumn("trading volume",col("# of shares")*col("trade price"))
                     .select("# of shares","trade price","trading volume")
```